# Using a vector and classes

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a problem that for you might look simple but I can't figure it out even though I really tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//Functions Prototypes ---
void create_object(std::vector <Movie> &);
std::string set_name();
int set_ryear();
double set_rating();

//Classes ---
class Movie {
public:
    std::string name;
    int release_year;
    double rating;
public:
    //Constructors
    Movie(std::string u_name, int u_release_year, double u_rating);
    ~Movie() {};
    Movie(const Movie &);
};


//MAIN ---
int main() {
    std::vector <Movie> Collection;
    create_object(Collection);

    return 0;
}

//Constructors ---
Movie::Movie(std::string u_name, int u_release_year, double u_rating)
    :name{ u_name }, release_year{ u_release_year }, rating{ u_rating }{

}

//Stand-Alone Functions ---
char get_selection() {
    char x;
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
}

void create_object(std::vector <Movie> &x) {
    std::string u_name = set_name();
    int u_ryear = set_ryear();
    double u_rating = set_rating();

    Movie User_Movie{ u_name,u_ryear,u_rating };
}

std::string set_name() {
    std::string x;

    std::cout << "Name: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

int set_ryear() {
    int x;

    std::cout << "Release year: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}

double set_rating() {
    double x;
    std::cout << "Rating: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    return x;
}
```

I'm just a beginner, so I don't know much, but for as much as I know classes should be types even if they are user-defined types, and they are supposed to give the possibility to be manipulated as primitive types.

So why, when I try to create a vector that expects a bunch of `Movie` types, or when I pass it by reference, I receive errors?

```
Error   C2664   'void create_object(std::vector &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<Movie,std::allocator<Movie>>' to 'std::vector &' 
Error   C2923   'std::vector': 'Movie' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'    
Error   C2065   'Movie': undeclared identifier
```

The main usage for it should be to be visible to all functions so that I can pass it to them as I want, and to make operations on its objects (like after creating a new object, I want to be able to add it into the collection using `push_back()` and all that stuff) after I create a menu system using `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared the `Movie` class by the time you reach this statement:

```
void create_object(std::vector <Movie> &);
```

The *correct* way to do C++ classes is to put the basic declaration in a separate file `movie.h` and then `#include` it in your code at the start.

If you cannot do that (although you really should), move the class declaration to the start of the file.

Comment: Wow... I guess the simple things are often the most problematic. Thank you for your help and time!